# How to pass locale variables into partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a project, there is a partial where image tag is used like this:

```
src='<%= image_url(image) %>'
```

Then how can I pass local to render this partial? I could not understand that.

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html

Comment: _This question should include more details and clarify the problem._

Comment: @SebastianPalma What else should I provide?

Comment: You talk about partials, tags, local variables but the only thing you add in your question is an uncomplete piece of code without context. You must keep in mind that people reading your question have no idea what you're seeing or know, so you must put that pretty clear in order to receive an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To learn how to pass local variables into partials, have a look at the [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) guide:

```
<%= render partial: "my_image_partial", locals: {image: @my_image} %>
```